# A Traceback while drawing the trajectory of gradient descent in 2D using TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to *draw the trajectory of gradient descent in 2D*. Unfortunately, I had the following traceback:

`InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1]`

I am using **TensorFlow v 1.13.1**, along with **Python v 3.6.7** from **Google COLAB**.

From the below code, I found that the variable `target` is of class `<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>`.
I tried to feed it as mentioned `feed_dict={features: x, target: y}`, but I still have the same traceback.

Here is the code I used for this task:

```
## BLOCK 1

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import animation, rc
import matplotlib_utils
from IPython.display import HTML, display_html
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

```
## BLOCK 2

tf.reset_default_graph()

# generate model data
N = 1000
D = 3
x = np.random.random((N, D))
w = np.random.random((D, 1))
y = x @ w + np.random.randn(N, 1) * 0.20

## Deep Learning steps:
# 1. Get input (features) and true output (target)
features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, D))
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

weights = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=(D, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

# 2. Compute the "guess" (predictions) based on the features and weights
predictions = features @ weights

# 3. Compute the loss based on the difference between the predictions and the target
loss = tf.reduce_mean((target - predictions) ** 2)

# 4. Update the weights (parameters) based on the gradient descent of the loss
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
step = optimizer.minimize(loss)

s = tf.Session()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
_, curr_loss, curr_weights = s.run([step, loss, weights], 
                             feed_dict={features: x, target: y})
```

I am expecting that the following code will run properly (traceback raised while running this code):

```
## BLOCK 3

# nice figure settings

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y_true_value = s.run(target)
level_x = np.arange(0, 2, 0.02)
level_y = np.arange(0, 3, 0.02)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(level_x, level_y)
Z = (X - y_true_value[0])**2 + (Y - y_true_value[1])**2
ax.set_xlim(-0.02, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-0.02, 3)
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
ax.scatter(*s.run(target), c='red')
contour = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10)
ax.clabel(contour, inline=1, fontsize=10)
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# start animation with empty trajectory
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

trajectory = [s.run(predictions)]

# one animation step (make one GD step)
def animate(i):
    s.run(step)
    trajectory.append(s.run(predictions))
    line.set_data(*zip(*trajectory))
    return (line,)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)
```

**Note**: the library `matplotlib_utils` can be found [here](https://github.com/hse-aml/intro-to-dl/blob/master/week2/matplotlib_utils.py)!

---

**Example**

This is an example in which the code runs perfectly.

If I run the following code instead of the second block, it displays a beautiful *gradient descent in 2D*.

```
y_guess = tf.Variable(np.zeros(2, dtype='float32'))
y_true = tf.range(1, 3, dtype='float32')

loss = tf.reduce_mean((y_guess - y_true + 0.5*tf.random_normal([2]))**2) 

optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.03, 0.5)
step = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=y_guess)
```

This trajectory is something like this:

[image: trajectory of gradient descent in 2D]

Adding this black of code will display perfect auto-generator of the *trajectory*:

```
## BLOCK 4

try:
    display_html(HTML(anim.to_html5_video()))
except (RuntimeError, KeyError):
    # In case the build-in renderers are unaviable, fall back to
    # a custom one, that doesn't require external libraries
    anim.save(None, writer=matplotlib_utils.SimpleMovieWriter(0.001))
```

Now I want to use my own code (second block of code) to draw such trajectory of gradient descent in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `feed_dict` argument with `tf.session.run`. Example:

```
s.run([step, loss, weights], feed_dict={features: x, target: y})
```

Explanation:
When the operation on the computation graph depends on a placeholder, they must be provided. Operations like `s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` do not depend on the placeholders, so not passing them does not raise an error.

Comment: Thanks, @theQmech. I added the line of code you have provided but I still have the same traceback.

Comment: Did you take care of all s.run() calls? Because I did and the code ran without any errors.

Comment: Thanks, @theQmech. I have added ```feed_dict={features: x, target: y}``` to all ```s.run()``` in **BLOCK 3** but I got this traceback: ```TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'```.

Comment: The asterisk in `ax.scatter(*s.run(target, fedd_dict=...), c='red')` is the trouble. Refer to this [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) and feed the arguments properly.

Comment: I have changed to this ```idx = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(y_true_value)]
ax.scatter(s.run(idx, y_true_value.all()), c='red')
``` and I go this traceback: ```TypeError: input must be a dictionary```. ((

Comment: The error is self-explanatory. If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, then `ax.scatter(range(len(y_true_value)), y_true_value, c='red')` should be enough. 

I suggest you to read the relevant documentation(both TF and matplotlib) more carefully to avoid running into future troubles.